# add,save contact for android in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i am doing a small game which gives user to play by name or choose a contact. i will tel what i done point wise

1. added menu to my app as index.html
   2.created namedailog.html (user inputs name to save in contacts)
   3.created namecontact.html (user can see the name saved from step 2 in contacts)

here is what i done

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // create
        var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
        contact.displayName = "Plumber";
        contact.nickname = "Plumber";       //specify both to support all devices
        var name = new ContactName();
        name.givenName = "Jane";
        name.familyName = "Doe";
        contact.name = name;

        // save
        contact.save(onSaveSuccess,onSaveError);
    }

    // onSaveSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSaveSuccess(contact) {
        alert("Save Success");
    }

    // onSaveError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onSaveError(contactError) {
        alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Find Contacts</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: question is adding a contact and saving it. the saved contact should appear in android contact list. i.e., i need to get this saved contact seraching in contacts also. sorry for my bad english, new to this forum

Comment: which phonegap/cordova version are you using? phonegap-1.0.0.js is so old

Comment: i'm using version-2.9.0. any idea on my question.